# #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysqli, update

Tengo 2 tablas una con los datos generales de Rutas y otra de Inscripciones de cada socio, quiero actualizar la tabla Rutas con los sumatorios de dos campos de la tabla de Inscripciones y me da el error:

> #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Este es el código:

```
UPDATE Rutas set socios = sisocios,
                 no_socios = nosocios
WHERE codigo_ruta = (select x.numconv, 
                            SUM(x.numsocios) as sisocios, 
                            SUM(x.numinvitados) as nosocios
                     FROM inscripcion x
                     where x.situac = 'A'
                     group by x.numconv)
```

Comment: Deberias mostrar la estructura de tus tablas

Comment: La estructura de la tabla RUTAS:
Columna Tipo
codigo_ruta (Primaria) varchar(15)
fecha_programa date
fecha_ini date
fecha_fin date
situac char(1)
descripcion text
plazas int(11)
socios int(11)
no_socios int(11)

Comment: La estructura de Inscripciones es :Columna Tipo
id_consulta (Primaria) int(11)
fecha_inscripcion datetime
numconv char(10)
dni char(11)
situac char(1)
nombre char(30)
apellidos char(50)
email char(40)
numsocios int(3)
numinvitados int(3)
observaciones varchar(250)
usualta char(15)

Comment: la solución es correcta, teniendo en cuenta tus aportaciones del resultado que daba el error, QUE SOLO DEBERÍA DEVOLVER UNA FILA..
¿es suficiente esta respuesta?

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado el problema: al usar el operador igual (=) hay asegurarte que sólo se devuelve una única fila, de lo contrario la base de datos no sabrá con qué valor comparar. Si quieres devolver más de una fila, deberías usar el operador IN. La solución es limitar los valores devueltos a uno solo, y el número de filas a una sola (o cambiar el operador por un IN).

El comentario me ha hecho plantear de otra manera y ya se ha resuelto, al final ha quedado así:

```
UPDATE Rutas K 
SET    socios = (
                     SELECT   SUM(x1.numsocios)
                     FROM     inscripcion x1
                     WHERE    x1.numconv = K.codigo_ruta
                          AND x1.situac ='A'
                     GROUP BY x1.numconv
                ),
       no_socios = (
                     SELECT   SUM(x2.numinvitados)
                     FROM     inscripcion x2
                     WHERE    x2.numconv = K.codigo_ruta
                          AND x2.situac ='A'
                     GROUP BY x2.numconv
                 )
```

Comment: @Alvaro increíble labor de mejora de contenido, chapeau!

Comment: @fedorqui realmente es lo que el usuario había puesto en los comentarios, simplemente lo he editado un poco.

Comment: Hola @fedorqui ¿cómo llegas a poner el código perfectamente de forma visual?, pues es como lo tengo en el PHP. GRACIAS MIL...